# How can I easily convert between the groupId form of a library and its associated path in the local repository?

Tags: maven, gradle, path, dependency-management

I am using gradle to install an Android AAR package (although, this could conceivably work with a JAR or any other artifact). I can install the artifact with `./gradlew install`. This will install it to my local maven repository, by default `~/.m2/repository`.

This works fine. Now, I need to create a new task that can work with the actual files of that repository. I can get all of the information I need, but I have the `groupId` in the form: `com.somecompany.project`, and I WANT it in the form: `com/somecompany/project` (since this is how it is stored in the local maven repository on the file system).

I know that I can just convert the `.` characters to `${file.separator}`, but, given that maven has to do this operation internally, is there a quick method for doing this that's part of the maven plugin? I'm hoping to be able to do something like:

```
def groupDirStructure = maven.convertGroupToPath(project.group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get at the file you should resolve it as a dependency rather than go searching for it on the file system.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

configurations {
    local
}

dependencies {
    local 'com.somecompany.project:module:1.0'
}

task copyArtifacts(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.local
    into "some/dir"
}
```

Comment: Hm... interesting. Well, actually what I want to do is _delete_ the file (i.e. remove it from the maven local repo using a ./gradlew task). Is this possible in the same manner?

Comment: In that case it would probably be better to just derive the file location from the GAV. The reason being that deleting the resolved artifact is not really sufficient. You really want to delete the whole directory, which also includes the POM files. This can still be problematic though because the maven-metadata.xml file will still contain the deleted version. This is a really easy way to corrupt your local maven repo and get it into a broken state.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too concerned about that, though, because, up to now, we've been _manually_ deleting those directories via the shell. We're only using it for testing our library locally, anyway, so it's not a huge deal.

Comment: Is there a better way to _remove_ a dependency from your local maven repo? I can install it with `./gradlew install`, but `./gradlew uninstall` or `./gradlew uninstallAll` doesn't seem to do it...

Comment: In that case I would still recommend just doing with your original plan. Deleting the files in configuration would just remove the artifacts and not the entire directory. I don't see an issue with doing a simple string replacement on the group name to determine the path.

Comment: No, there is no standard mechanism for removing published artifacts.